# How would I go about in making a neck strap?

Tags: objects

I was wondering how I would start to make a neck strap, for example one on binoculars in blender. Maybe somehow apply physics too it to make it more realistic as well.

[image]

[image]

Like the straps on the images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Model a small section of the strap. Add a curve object. Give the strap an array modifier and a curve deform modifier, set the curve for the curve modifier and set the array to fit curve and select the curve. You can set the start and end caps of the array to get a 'loop' at each end.

[image]

Now when you adjust the curve the strap will deform with it. Use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to 'twist' a curve point. For ease of animation you can add a hook to each curve point with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> -> Hook to new object.

[image]

For physics you could set a small 'cube' at each curve point as the hook object (or make it the parent to the empty) and set rigid body physics on them.

Comment: Sambler I just want you to know the ctrl+T info you provided just brought me massive relief and a dopamine hit...lol. I've been trying to figure out if that function existed. So, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the binoculars are going to hang around someone's neck, you could try doing a cloth simulation on a strip of mesh.  The problem is that leather straps are going to be stiff across the grain and pliant along it, so getting a mesh with a cloth modifier to deform correctly will take a great deal of tweaking.
If you're just making a still images, then i'd just try making a mesh and using falloff selection to bend and twist it the way you want it.
The laplacian deform modifier is useful in these situations for preventing kinks and self-intersection.
You can also making an armature and skinning it, but I don't know very much about rigging.