# Create Additional Curves Morphing Between 2 Input Curves

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm wondering if there is a way to create multiple curve objects that morph between two input curve objects.

In the illustration below, the input would be curve 1 and 4. I'd like to automatically create curves 2 and 3. I'd like to be able to create around 30 curves in between the 2 input curves. I'm guessing this would need to be done by python scripting.

[image: create curve morph between two input curves]

Comment: If the curves have the same number of vertex you could try doing it with one single curve instead, and use *Shapekeys* for morphing

Comment: Use [hooks to animate each point](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26874/935) moving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work only if both initial and final morphing shape have the same number of vertex.

If they don't you can always add a few more to the one with the least vertex, if moving them in place is not too much of a hassle.

Then create one single curve, shape it as desired.

Add two new *Shapekeys* to it, one *Basis* and one with the desired final morphing shape.

Now make a few copies of the curve (non-linked clones), and on each one gradually increase the *Value* for the shapekey.

For an even constant morphing divide the percentage by the number of "snapshots" you plan to have.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Now to turn it into a python script! Thanks!

Comment: Yep, sounds like a good candidate for a script to simplify the tedious workflow. Can't help you there much though, coding is not my forte